# NFS mount is gone after reboot, but present in fstab

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, mount, fstab

I have added the following to `/etc/fstab`, which I understood would automatically mount upon startup of the machine.

```
192.168.1.236:/volume1/Media /nfs/plex nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

However every time I reboot my server I have to run `sudo mount -a` in order to see anything in the /nfs/plex directory. Otherwise it is empty.

The network storage location (Synology NAS) was online before the server.

Comment: `intr` does nothing; why is it there? and `nofail` prevents error reporting; it also should not be there, especially when you're having a problem and need to know what it is.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: I had to copy the command from elsewhere as I was in a hurry to get it set up. Where are the logs?